# Character Array to string in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

The output of the [Character] Array currently is:

```
["E", "x", "a", "m", "p", "l", "e"]
```

It should be:

```
Example
```

It could be that `"` is in the array, like this: `"""`. That output should be `"`.

Thank you!

Comment: You'll get much better answers if you show the declaration and definition of your array.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The other answer(s) cover the case where your array is one of `String` elements (which is most likely the case here: since you haven't supplied us the type of the array, we could use Swift own type inference rules to speculatively infer the type to be `[String]`).

In case the elements of your array are in fact of type `Character`, however, you could use the [`Character` sequence initializer of `String`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1641169-init) directly:

```
let charArr: [Character] = ["E", "x", "a", "m", "p", "l", "e"]
let str = String(charArr) // Example
```

---

W.r.t. your comment below: if your example array is, for some reason, one of `Any` elements (which is generally not a good idea to use explicitly, but sometimes the case when recieving data from some external source), you first need to perform an attempted conversion of each `Any` element to `String` type, prior to concenating the converted elements to a single `String` instance. After the conversion, you will be working with an array of `String` elements, in which case the methods shown in the other answers will be the appropriate method of concenation:

```
// e.g. using joined()
let arr: [Any] = ["E", "x", "a", "m", "p", "l", "e"]
let str = arr.flatMap { $0 as? String }.joined()
print(str) // example
```

You could naturally also (attempt to) convert from `Any` to `Character` elements, but even in this case you would have to go via `String` instances, which means that for the `[Any]` case, the `joined()` alternative above is to prefer over the one below:

```
let arr: [Any] = ["E", "x", "a", "m", "p", "l", "e"]
let str = String(arr.flatMap { ($0 as? String)?.characters.first })
print(str) // example
```

Comment: I forgot to mention indeed that the array type is [Character]. When I try your solution, I get this error in red: " 'init'  has been renamed to 'init(describing:)'" :(

Comment: @Petravd1994: Could it be that you have an *optional* array?

Comment: I changed it to let str = String(describing: charr) however the output is exactly the same as the array... it is really frustrating now. I made this array: var Array1: [Any] = [] and than appended elements by using Array1.append(Array2[0]). Now I want it that Array1 is converted to a string without the "" and ",". The array is not optional

Comment: `String(describing:)` produces a string with essentially the same output as `print()`. Why are you creating the array as an `[Any]`? Swift has no idea that it's an `[Character]`, so it doesn't allow you to call the proper initilizer with it.

Answer (score 11):

Just use `joined()` with default `""` separator:

```
let joinedString = ["E", "x", "a", "m", "p", "l", "e"].joined()
```

Comment: It would be worthwhile to see how this compares in performance to the String initializer. I suspect that will be faster, because it could skip on the memory reallocation

Answer (score 5):

```
let e = ["E", "x", "a", "m", "p", "l", "e"]
print(e.reduce ("", +))
```

Comment: That implementation isn't performant (it can require a `log_2(count)` number of memory reallocations. It also isn't necessary, because `String` has an initializer that constructs a string from a `Character` array.

Comment: You should probably just joined() method, but nevertheless the apple documentation does claim "Behind the scenes, Swift’s compiler optimizes string usage so that actual copying takes place only when absolutely necessary. This means you always get great performance when working with strings as value types." I suppose I should look at the disassembly and see what it actually emits.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: I would appreciate taking a look at your findings. The issue here is not the copying that occurs due to value semantics, but the reallocation that's necessary when appending to a string whose length is about to exceed its allocated capacity.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov note that `String` instances in Swift use an exponential growth strategy to (re-)allocate its contiguous storage, with the effect that appending characters to a `String` instance will be a constant time operation when amortized(/avaraged) over many invocations. Reallocation should not be an issue in the example above (`reduce` being slower than e.g. classic loops in some contexts is another matter). See e.g. the comment section _Performance Optimizations_ in [swift/stdlib/public/core/String.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift).

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Just a thought: while it is very interesting from a theoretical approach to discuss performance of various Swift operations, this subject in itself (w.r.t. the dicussion we had the other day on instantiation/mutation of arrays) may also be a danger (just as "bad practices" would) to Swift beginners; focusing on pre-mature performance optimizations before these are even shown as an issue in a profiler. Best practices is great, but one of the core concepts of Swift is that developers using it should be able to trust the compiler (and listen to a profiler for possible issues).

Comment: (... just an ellipsis; Swift is neither C not C++, but a safe, user-friendly language that may be deeply dwelled into w.r.t. performance, or simply used off-the-bat, ascertaining naturally that we don't use outright bad practices. I personally believe, imho, that it is much better for beginner to focus on learning the tools such as debugging and profiling rather than putting too much time into sub-optimizations of core concepts, even if some of us find the latter subject very interesting. And naturally, putting time into learning how to treat and safely unwrap optionals :) ).

Comment: So I didn't have much luck with either the SIL or the Assembly so I decided to just profile the methods instead.  I created 100,000 5-8 character random strings and measured the average time to .join them at 0.066 seconds and to .reduce them at  0.039 seconds.  It turns out reduce is much faster.  Maybe the compiler is eliminating the function call and putting in reduce as a loop?