# Convert array to string? in Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift3, actionsheetpicker

I am working with the ActionSheetPicker 3.0 (https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) picker and am having a newbie problem of working with the return values from the ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.  I've got the control running and can return values from it, but I want to be able to put the return values from the picker into separate variables or into something that I can join together.  I've found numerous examples, but can't figure out how to get them to work.

What I think I've found through debugging is that ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker returns an array of Any?.

Debugging shows the following:

values  Any?    some
payload_data_0  Builtin.RawPointer  0x60800044fdb0  0x000060800044fdb0 -> 0x000000010dacddd8 (void *)0x000000010dacdf18: __NSArrayI
payload_data_1  Builtin.RawPointer  0x335392d30 0x0000000335392d30
payload_data_2  Builtin.RawPointer  0x10d28d798 0x000000010d28d798 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue + 35
instance_type   Builtin.RawPointer  0x60800005d5c8  0x000060800005d5c8

values is the return value from the picker.

A couple things that I've tried are:

```
let stringText: String? = String(describing: values)
print(stringText)
```

This prints:

Optional("Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x60800044be20>(\nOne,\nMany,\naaa\n)\n)")

I've also tried:

```
print("\(values as! NSArray)")
```

This is the closest I've gotten to the results I'm looking for which is:

(
    One,
    Many,
    aaa
)

Can anyone provide some assistance getting the value of 'values' into something that I can separate into three different string variables?

My code for the picker is:

```
    let a = ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.init(title: "Fertilizer Setup", rows: [

        // TODO: Read values from database
        ["One", "Two", "A lot"],
        ["Many", "Many more", "Infinite"],
        ["aaa","sss","ccc","xxxx"]
        ], initialSelection: [0, 0, 0],
           doneBlock: {
               picker, indexes, values in

               let stringText: String? = String(describing: values)

               print(stringText)

               print("\(values as! NSArray)")
    },
           cancel: {ActionMultipleStringCancelBlock in return }, origin: sender)

    a?.setCancelButton(UIBarButtonItem(title: "My own title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil))
    a?.show()
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string) or of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597189/character-array-to-string-in-swift)

Comment: Option click on `values`, and you'll see its inferred type. What does it show?

Comment: @Yonlif, I did see those posts, but I wasn't able to get the examples to work with my solution.

Comment: @Alexander,  Option + Click doesn't show the type.  I get a popup that says No Quick Help.  I am able to get this though.     Printing description of values:
▿ Optional<Any>
  ▿ some : 3 elements
    ▿ 0 : One
    ▿ 1 : Many
    ▿ 2 : aaa

Comment: So it *is* an NSArray. Is it an `NSArray` containing only strings?

Comment: In the end it will be a picker with three columns, string, int, string.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  I changed my doneBlock code to be:

```
doneBlock: {
            picker, indexes, values in
                 let fertilzerPicker:  NSArray = values as! NSArray               
                 self.row.value!.name = fertilzerPicker[0] as! String
                 self.row.value!.amount = fertilzerPicker[1] as! Int
                 self.row.value!.unitOfMeasurement = fertilzerPicker[2] as! String
}
```

The key line being:

```
let fertilzerPicker:  NSArray = values as! NSArray
```

Creating fertilzerPicker allowed me to get the individual elements of the array.